# How can a C++ reference be changed (by any means necessary)

Tags: c++

The C++ language doesn't let you change a reference after it is assigned.  However, I had a debugging need/desire to change the reference to help debug something.  Is there a hacky way to basically overwrite the reference implementation with a new pointer? Once you get an address to the object you want to change, you can cast it to whatever you want and overwrite it.  I could not figure out how to get a memory address of the underlying reference instance; using `&` to dereference the reference doesn't give you the address of the reference, but the address of the object pointed to by the reference.

I realize this is obviously going to invoke undefined behavior, and this is just an experiment. A third party library has a bug with global reference that was not getting constructed before the code is exercised, and I want to see if I can fix it by setting the reference myself.  At this point, it became a challenge to see if it is even possible.  I know you can do this in assembly language, if you can reference the symbol table directly.

I imagine something like this. These are globally scoped variables.

```
Apple a;
Apple& ref = a;
```

Later I want `ref` to refer to a new object instance `b` and leave `a` alone.

```
Apple b;

ref = b; // that doesn't work. that justs sets a=b.

&ref = &b; // that doesn't work. the compiler complains.

uint64_t addr  = find_symbol_by_any_means_necessary(ref);
*(Apple**)addr = &b; // this should work if I could get addr
```

Please don't remind me this is a bad idea. I know it is a bad idea. Think of it as a challenge. This is for debug only, to test a hypotheses quickly. I want to learn something about the internals of C++ binary code.  (Please tell me if it is impossible because of system page protection... I suppose you could get a seg fault if the references are placed in a holy place).

(The system is CentOS 7, compiler is Intel although I could use gcc for this experiment).

Comment: Uhhh, are you sure that doesn't work? Try this code: `Apple a; Apple &a_ref; Apple b; a_ref = b;` with a class `Apple` which monitors when it's copy-constructed, move-assigned, etc. I'm fairly sure that you'll see that `a_ref` now points to `b`; it's not just copying the data. It would if you did `a = b`, but you aren't.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, Using the assignment operator on a reference assigns to the referred-to object.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: The code example you've given won't compile. `Apple &a_ref;` is invalid. The following code: `Apple a; Apple &a_ref = a; a_ref = b;` is equivalent in every way to `Apple a; a = b;`

Comment: @BillLynch Whoops, I mistyped. I meant what you wrote. And... huh, alright.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since the whole point of using a reference is to forbid someone/yourself to change the address being referred to. You can see it as a `Apple* const a` which is a read-only.

Comment: Look up the static initialization order fiasco in the C++ FAQ. Or just fix the thing by replacing the (presumably) global with a Meyers' singleton. Preferentially use your debugger, not your code, to do debugger things such as replacing a value.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf using the debugger is a good idea - except gdb seems to be pretty bad at debugging code that is hit before main. It won't even show me the code (complains about some obscure issue with a crti.s file not found) probably because the Intel compile and gdb don't get along... sigh...

Comment: btw, I did fix the underlying issue with a Meyer's singleton.

Comment: To answer this question, you probably need to know at compiler (or at least which ABI) is in use.  You certainly can't do it legally in C++, as you know, and you'll need to have a good understanding of how your compiler represents references.  I think it's going to be easier to modify and recompile the library (assuming it's not closed-source or something).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to re-direct the object that a standalone reference variable references.

If a reference is contained in a `struct` as a member variable, you can easily change the object the reference variable references. It's most likely UB but it works with my current version of g++, g++ 4.8.4.

Here's an example program that demonstrates a method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct Foo
{
   int& ref;
};

int main()
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 20;

   Foo foo = {a};  // foo.ref is a reference to a
   std::cout << foo.ref << std::endl;

   // Use memcpy to change what foo.ref references
   int* bPtr = &b;
   std::memcpy(&foo, &bPtr, sizeof(bPtr));

   // Now, foo.ref is a reference to b
   std::cout << foo.ref << std::endl;

   // Changing foo.ref changes b
   foo.ref = 30;
   std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
```

Comment: +1 I can't change the reference otherwise the code will break ... but you've given me an idea. Place a sacrificial variable *before* the reference and assume that the sacrificial variable and the reference are placed sequentially in memory. Get the address of the sacrificial variable and add a few byte offset to get to the referene...

Answer (score 0):

it's generally not possible, because the fact that a reference is not reseatable allows a lot of optimizations.

For instance, a reference is often implemented as a pointer, but the compiler may also notice that you often use an fixed offset. So besides storing the pointer, the compiler may decide to store the pointer plus offset. It may even decide to only store the pointer plus offset.

Another optimization is to store the reference as an address in a CPU register. Since it can't change, the compiler doesn't need to reload it.

So your statement that you can change it in assembly is rather misleading. You have no idea what the representation of the reference is after optimization, and this optimization will be situationally dependent.